# How to show two fields in view which is of same column in class in openERP

Tags: python, openerp-7

In openERP purchase module I'm having two fields for Purchase Order Amendment which are of 'ordered quantity-old' and 'ordered quantity-new' those  retrieving data from same column. Now I want to show

**1.**
One field for 'ordered quantity- old' which should show current purchase order's 'ordered quantity' actual value from table and it should be a read only field,

**2.**
another field for 'ordered quantity- new' which should not show any value(should be 0) and once the new changed quantity is given it should update the column in the table

How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your idea is to gave 2 fields but actually have 1 field, which can't be done. So simply create **new field** for ordered quantity - new and let it be **read-only**. And when new quantity is given simply **update that field**.
If you still find that undesirable, set second field to be invisible, and use it as helper field. Only you will now its there, store value in it and when confirming to new field simply take/store old value in it for history purposes.

In view then you will have old and new, you will have splited logic which is good and user will have easier time to understand.

Third option is related field if you have connection to different table.

```
'model':fields.related('model_id','model',type="char", size=64, string="Model name")
```

First parameter is field in current table to which this is referenced, second if field that will be pulled from referenced table, rest is known :)

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i dont want to create a new column,instead i can create a **related column** for that **ordered quantity column**. Can you tell me how to create a related column for a column that is in different table? As Im new to openERP can you give a tip for that?